# Why is Interop.WMPLib unable to load assembly in Release mode, but works in Debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, controls, winforms-interop

I have added the Windows Media Player com control into my toolbox and then used the control successfully on a Form in Debug mode.

However, when I try running the application in Release mode it errors with...

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.WMPLib, ... or one of its
>   dependecies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

Through some tracing I've established that the error occurs not when creating the control but on the EndInit method.

```
Public Sub New

    InitializeComponent() 

    wmp = New AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer()
    wmp.BeginInit()
    wmp.Enabled = True
    wmp.Name = "wmp"
    wmp.OcxState = CType(resources.GetObject("wmp.OcxState"), AxHost.State)
    Me.Controls.Add(wmp)
    Me.Controls.SetChildIndex(wmp, 0)
    wmp.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    wmp.EndInit()   ' <<< errors here !

End Sub
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd double check the Release/Debug build configurations; My best guess is that Debug targets 32 bit, and Release 64 bit or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the Platform target setting in the Debug configuration.  Possibly weeks ago, maybe even in a previous version of Visual Studio.  But didn't change it in the Release configuration.  It is one of the settings that is configuration specific.

Comment: That was it. I'm running on a 64-bit machine, and the debug target was set to X86 (for edit and continue), but the release target was set to Any CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that only one assembly (AxInterop.WMPLib.dll) was copied to the Bebug/ Release folder after build. Interop.WMPLib.dll is missing, when i copy it manually of course it runs. Now im  looking for a way to either manually copy it (within the csproj file) or find another way...